# Цикличная смена слова в заголовке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как можно реализовать так, чтобы слово "съезжало" сверху при появлении

```js
const fruit = document.getElementById('type');
let a = ['груши', 'персики', 'киви'];

let counter = 0;
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  if (counter == a.length) counter = 0;
  fruit.classList.toggle('active');
  setTimeout(() => {
    fruit.textContent = a[counter];
    fruit.classList.toggle('active');
    counter++;
  }, 400)
}, 3000)
```

```css
#type {
  transition: opacity .4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#type.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Я ем <span class="active" id='type'>яблоки</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким образом:

```
#type {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  #type.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
```